# Is it possible to use libraries-extend from a module (instead of theme)?

Tags: 8, theming, media, .info

**Problem/Motivation**

I'm interested in altering/overriding the little bit of HTML markup that's output by core, in my case `Drupal.theme.mediaEmbedEditButton` (from `core/modules/media/js/media_embed_ckeditor.theme.js`), but without hacking core, of course. It seems I could do this in a custom theme by adding:

```
libraries-extend:
  media/media_embed_ckeditor_theme:
    - my_theme/my_library
```

(plus the info for `my_library` in `my_theme.libraries.yml`, and the JS file in my theme with the function that would return the new markup).

However, since this shows up in places like /node/add/page that only uses the admin theme (we're using Seven), such additions to `my_theme` wouldn't apply.  While it seems like I could make a bare-bones `my_admin_theme`, pulling in Seven as base, I'd like to keep this override near other related customizations in a custom module (I also ran into other cans of worms when I tried this as a proof of concept).

**What (else) I've tried**

I tried putting in `libraries-extend:` from above in `my_module.info.yml` (plus the addition to `my_module.libraries.yml` and the new JS, of course), but this didn't seem to work (kinda not surprising, since the docs I'm finding only seem to reference `libraries-extend` in the same breath as themes).  I also tried using `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` in `my_module.module` to attach my override library via `$element['#attached']['library'][]` but didn't have luck there either.

Am I stuck with with making a custom admin theme if I want to use `libraries-extend`? (I'm guessing this is also a problem for `libraries-override`.) Or am I missing some hook or something I could instead add to my custom module to accomplish overriding the output made by `Drupal.theme.mediaEmbedEditButton`?

Comment: It does look like extending is for themes only, but even so - it seems a shame to override and maintain your own version of the whole library for this (if a new method gets added in the core version you'll have to add it in your own version and so on). I'd be tempted to just monkey patch that one function - declare your own library with a JS file containing (a more complete version of) `Drupal.theme.mediaEmbedEditButton = function() { return 'html'; }`. Make sure your library has a dependency on the core library, so its JS is included first, and the browser should do the rest

Comment: My hope was indeed to have to maintain just a JS file basically containing little more than `Drupal.theme.mediaEmbedEditButton = function() { return 'custom button html'; }` (plus the necessary `library-extend` and custom library stuff to have it picked up). I definitely don't want to override and maintain a whole core library. Sorry if that wasn't clear from my long-winded text, haha. The small JS worked when I made a custom admin theme (other unrelated issues notwithstanding). Just thought it was odd to only be supported for themes, not modules. Maybe I should file a feature request.

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg this is a great question, well-researched and documented. I think the answer is clear, though: you _will_ need to create a custom admin theme to avoid the chore of overriding and maintaining a whole core library.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, read this:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/drupal-8-development/9781788290401/080b0131-1b64-4900-8535-55c82dba4200.xhtml

> ## Manipulating libraries from hooks
>
> Modules have the ability to provide dynamic library definitions and alter libraries. A module can use the `hook_library_info()` hook to provide a library definition. This is not the recommended way to define a library, but it is provided for edge use cases.
>
> Modules do not have the ability to use `libraries-override` or `libraries-extend`, and need to rely on the `hook_library_info_alter()` hook. You can check out this hook in `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/theme.api.php` or at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.
>
> source: **[Drupal 8 Development Cookbook - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/product/drupal-8-development-cookbook-second-edition/9781788290401)** by [Matt Glaman](https://www.drupal.org/u/mglaman)