# Why does libraries-extend not change part of the styles of the module DropzoneJS?

Tags: theming, 9

I use the **DropzoneJS** module. To change to change part of the styles written here: /modules/contrib/dropzonejs/css/dropzone.widget.css I use **libraries-extend**.

In the files of my theme **particle** I wrote:

particle.info.yml:

```
libraries-extend:
   dropzonejs/widget:
     - particle/dropzone-custom
```

particle.libraries.yml:

```
dropzone-custom:
   version: VERSION
   css:
     theme:
       css/style.css: {}
```

style.css:

```
.dropzone {
  background: #f1fbff;
  border: 2px dashed #2cb7f4;
  border-radius: 37px;
}
```

And then I cleaned the cache. But styles are not applied.

Where is the error? Is something missing?

Comment: I believe modules can't use the library-extend and its only themes that can https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293532/is-it-possible-to-use-libraries-extend-from-a-module-instead-of-theme

Comment: The OP is using it in a theme (since he says *my theme **particle***).

Comment: Are you checking this on a page that uses the *particle* theme? Is the theme enabled? Does the theme have a *.info.yml* file? Is that file correctly named after the theme machine name?